# The Regex Rule of Flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am confused about the rule of flex lexer

My lexer can recognize the decimal and hex, but when I want to make a union for both of them as the Integer.

flex tells me it's `test.l:13: unrecognized rule`

here's my lexer file:

`test.l`

```
%{  
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int yylval;
%}

digit       [0-9]
decimal     ^({digit}|[1-9]{digit}+)$
hex         0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+
integer     {hex}|{decimal}

%%
{integer}     {printf("integer - %s \n", yytext);}
%%

// run function
int yywrap(void) { 
    return 1; 
}

int main(void) {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need to anchor your `decimal` pattern? The way it is written, it will only match a number which is by itself on a line, without even any white space.

Anyway, it's the anchor which creates a problem. In (f)lex, `^` can only appear at the beginning of a pattern, and the macro expansion of `{hex}|{decimal}` has the `^` in the middle.

Changing it to `{decimal}|{hex}` won't help because flex normally surrounds macro expansions with parentheses to avoid incorrect operator grouping. (The parentheses are not inserted if the macro ends with `$`, but the immediate replacement body of `{integer}` doesn't end with a `$`.)

That effectively makes it impossible to use `^` anchors in macros, and hard to use `$`. You probably don't need these anchors at all, so the easiest solution is likely to just get rid of them. But if you do need to anchor your patterns, you must do so in the rule itself, outside any macro.

You might also consider not relying on flex macros. Like C macros, they are not nearly as useful as they might at first appear. If you want meaningful names for character ranges, you'll find that flex already provides them: `[[:digit:]]` is `[0-9]`; `[[:xdigit:]]` is `[0-9a-fA-F]`, and so on (the same categories as provided in C's `<ctypes.h>` header).